# What is the difference between noiseless and AWGN channels in terms of channel capacity?

Tags: noise

What is the difference between noiseless and additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN) channels in terms of channel capacity?

Comment: Can you add some context & spell out your acronyms? I don't know if people will be able to answer your question as stated.

Comment: A noiseless channel has infinite capacity at all temperatures.  An additive white Gaussian channel also can have infinite capacity but only at a temperature of _absolute zero_ $-273.15\ldots^{\circ} K$.